# DataGridView checkbox click calls DatagridView.CommitEdt() three times, why?

Tags: c#, winforms

please refer to my  [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPZSWUmFmcE&feature=player_detailpage) video to see a video capture of what im talking about : )

I have a simple windows app with a datagridview with a checkbox column. I want to check the check/uncheck status of cell so that I can color the cell if it's checked.

I have use the CurrentCellDirtyStateChange() and CellValueChange()... what I don't understand when I simply check a checkbox why the control calls the DataGrdview.CommitEdit(...) three times?

here is the code Load() will fill the datagridview with data fetched from DB and this works fine. but with the CommitEdit() which gets called 3 times in a single simple check to a check box

```
 private void dgvList_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this condition tells the controller that datagridview is filled with rows.
        //else throws a runtime error
        if (isGridReady == true)
        {
            if (dgvList.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
            {
                dgvList.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            } 
        }
    }

    private void dgvList_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (isGridReady == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dgvList[3, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(dgvList[3, e.RowIndex].Value) == true)
            {

                dgvList[3, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else
                dgvList[3, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
        }

    }
```

thanks

Comment: Please post your code